# Add module name in winston log entries

Tags: node.js, winston

Is there a possibility to save the current module name in order to be printed automatically in [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) log entries when they are called later?

Currently, when I want to print the module name in logs, I have to add it manually:

```
var logHeader = 'mymodule'

log.info(logHeader + 'Hello')
```

For example, with [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug), you can do (ignore the log format feature `%s` for now):

```
var debug = require('debug')('http')
  , name = 'My App'

debug('booting %s', name);
```

This will prin `http` prefix before the log:

> http booting My App

Can this be done in winston? I have searched in the documentation but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found a better way to do this.

I added an additional layer over the `winston` logger, in this case a function, that keeps the module name for each module that needs the logger. So when a module `require`s my new logger, it actually calls the exported function with the module name, in this case `__filename`.

#### log.js

```
var winston = require('winston')

var winstonLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File) ({
            filename: 'MyLogs.txt',
            handleExceptions: true,
            humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
            level: 'info',
            timestamp: true,
            json: false
        }),
        new (winston.transports.Console) ({
            level: 'info',
            prettyPrint: true,
            colorize: true,
            timestamp: true
        })
    ]
})

module.exports = function(fileName) {    
    var myLogger = {
        error: function(text) {
            winstonLogger.error(fileName + ': ' + text)
        },
        info: function(text) {
            winstonLogger.info(fileName + ': ' + text)
        }
    }

    return myLogger
}
```

#### module1.js

```
var log = require('log')(__filename)

log.info('Info log example')
```

> info: C:\Users\user1\project\module1.js: Info log example

#### module2.js

```
var log = require('log')(__filename)

log.error('Error log example')
```

> error: C:\Users\user1\project\module2.js: Error log example

Also, this way, I didn't need to change anywhere the way I submit a text log; `log.info('text')` stays exactly like before.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this solution and tried to find if anyone else did it and your solution is much better than what was in my mind.

Comment: this works fine until you need to log objects, then the output is something like `path-to-file: [Object object]`

Answer (score 28):

This is what **Child Loggers** are for. They might not have been available when this question was asked, but for future reference, you can create your main logger instance and then export a function that creates a child logger with some default options.

```js
// logging.js
const winston = require('winston') 

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.printf(options => {
        // you can pass any custom variable in options by calling
        // logger.log({level: 'debug', message: 'hi', moduleName: 'my_module' })
        return `[${options.moduleName}] ${options.level}: ${options.message}$`;
      })
    })
  ]
});

module.exports = function(name) {
  // set the default moduleName of the child
  return logger.child({moduleName: name});
}
```

Then at the top of each module, import the child using:

```js
// my_module.js
const logger = require('./logging.js')('my_module_name');

logger.error('computer says no');
// output:
// [my_module_name] error: computer says no
```

Comment: You can also export additional loggers and simply import then individually.

`export const databaseLogger = logger.child({ label: 'database' });`

Comment: This is great, and I'm gonna start using it, but it doesn't handle well with exceptionHandlers configuration - https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1693 , that's a shame, cause it means that if a dev forgets to try catch and the code throws, the logs won't be consistent

Comment: actually I can change the format of the exception log but it seems there's no options.moduleName (what we overrode) in the case of an exception, so I made some changes:  
module.exports = moduleName => {
  this.moduleName = moduleName;
  return logger;
};

and the format now uses this.moduleName instead of options.moduleName

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a [custom log format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#custom-log-format) with *Winston* -

```
var moduleName = 'myModule';

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      formatter: function(options) {
        // Return string will be passed to logger. 
        return moduleName + ' - ' + (options.message ? options.message : '')
      }
    })
  ]
});


logger.info('This is a log message');
```

This will print -

```
myModule - This is a log message
```

So your module name will be appended to every log messsage.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will append a string to all log messages. I am asking about appending module name to log messages from that module.

Comment: Yes so you'll need to instantiate a unique logger for each of your modules similar to the way you would do for `debug` module.

Comment: Instantiating a logger for each of modules is never a good idea. Rather 1st answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

With **winston v3.3.3** you can do this by using `winston.format.label` and a customization of `winston.format.printf`:

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.label({label: 'mymodule'}),
    winston.format.printf(({label, message}) => {
      return `${label}: ${message}`;
    })
  ),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
  ],
});

logger.info('Hello, World!'); // prints "mymodule: Hello, World!"
```